# Best way to manage 2 databases (dev and prod) with sensitive data

Tags: mysql, database, version-control

I have 2 DB's where one is my development DB and the other one is a production DB.
Some of the tables contain system information that I can change freely but some of the tables contain sensitive information that I must **not** change or delete in anyway.
Is there a concept of working in such constraints that applies to this situation on how to manage system updates?
I have tried explaining best as I can but further questions and notes would probably allow me to more clarify the situation.

**EDIT**
I'm trying to write and update bash script so that it will automatically manage updating to a new version.
Is there a way to flag to mysqldump which tables I wish to export only the structure of and which tables to export with structure and data and additionally to merge new data into existing rows in empty cells but to not overwrite existing data in non-empty cell?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect us to say beyond that you should make sure that such data is not changed or deleted during system changes...

Comment: Perhaps you should study the itil framework and implement it in your company.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I think that's the direction I needed. thank you.